# The save function in mongoose not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend, mongoose-schema

I have an schema and when I am trying to update an array in database the file is not getting updated and the array is always empty.
When I print the post after updating it it do print the array with one comment which I just added but it is not saved in the database.
Most probably my I am not saving the updated file correctly into the database

Here is my comment_controller

```
const Comment = require('../models/comment');
const Post = require('../models/post');

module.exports.create = function(req, res){
    Post.findById(req.body.postId, (err, post) => {
        //if the post is found
        if(post){
            Comment.create({
                content: req.body.comment,
                user: req.user._id,
                post: req.body.postId
            },
            (err, currcomment) => {
                if(err)
                    console.log(err);
                post.comment.push(currcomment);
                post.markModified('comment');
                post.save(function(err, doc) {
                    if (err) return console.error(err);
                    console.log("Document inserted succussfully!");
                  });
                    console.log(post);
                return res.redirect('/')
            }
            );
        }
        else{
            return res.redirect('/')
        }

    })
};
```

Here is my comments schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        content: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        //comment belongs to a user
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        post: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Post'
        }
    },

    {timestamps: true}
);

const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);

module.exports = Comment;
```

the post.save() is giving this warning/error

```
 Error: Post validation failed: comment: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"_id":"5fc0dfec4c87ad723b06d6eb","content":"sadfasdf","user":"5fba3cbd01b2310b7aba868b","post":"5fc0de91fc0ca96fd0b331df","createdAt":"2020-11-27T11:15:56.991Z","updatedAt":"2020-11-27T11:15:56.991Z","__v":0}]" at path "comment"
    at ValidationError.inspect (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:47:26)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:491:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:189:10)
    at Object.formatWithOptions (util.js:84:12)
    at Console.(anonymous function) (console.js:196:15)
    at Console.warn (console.js:213:31)
    at /home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/controllers/comment_controller.js:19:45
    at /home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4846:16
    at /home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
    at /home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4869:21
    at $__save.error (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:500:16)
    at /home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/kareem/index.js:246:48
    at next (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/kareem/index.js:167:27)
    at next (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/kareem/index.js:169:9)
    at Kareem.execPost (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/kareem/index.js:217:3)
    at _handleWrapError (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/kareem/index.js:245:21)
  errors:
   { comment:
      { ValidatorError: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"_id":"5fc0dfec4c87ad723b06d6eb","content":"sadfasdf","user":"5fba3cbd01b2310b7aba868b","post":"5fc0de91fc0ca96fd0b331df","createdAt":"2020-11-27T11:15:56.991Z","updatedAt":"2020-11-27T11:15:56.991Z","__v":0}]" at path "comment"
          at _init (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:691:37)
          at init (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:657:5)
          at model.Document.$__init (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:586:3)
          at model.syncWrapper [as $__init] (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/kareem/index.js:234:23)
          at model.Document.init (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:545:8)
          at completeOne (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2844:12)
          at model.Query.Query._completeOne (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2073:7)
          at Immediate.Query.base.findOne.call (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2117:10)
          at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/yuganksingh/me/Learn Full stack WEb-Dev/CODING NINJAS/Backend/instaKiloGram/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:116:16)
          at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
          at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
          at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'cast',
        path: 'comment',
        value:
         '[{"_id":"5fc0dfec4c87ad723b06d6eb","content":"sadfasdf","user":"5fba3cbd01b2310b7aba868b","post":"5fc0de91fc0ca96fd0b331df","createdAt":"2020-11-27T11:15:56.991Z","updatedAt":"2020-11-27T11:15:56.991Z","__v":0}]',
        reason: [CastError] } },
  _message: 'Post validation failed' }
```

The whole code is available here
https://github.com/YugankSingh/instaKiloGram

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using mongoose version 5.10.16, please change it to 5.10.15.
Check this GitHub issue thread https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9585#issue-751097126.
5.10.16 is totally broken.

Comment: I checked package.json its 
    "mongoose": "^5.10.15",

Comment: Please don't use any tilde(~) and caret(^), just do "mongoose": "5.10.15" in package.json.

Comment: the same problem is occurring no change